# Is there a insight-like frontend for gdb?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, frontend

I want to follow Jeff Duntemann's Assembly book and he uses insight as a frontend for gdb. I managed to set up an old virtual machine with insight, but maybe unsurprisingly it has some issues. My understanding is that insight is not supported any more so I am trying to find another frontend for gdb.

I tried gdbgui, but it doesn't show me the memory and from what I've seen from a couple of other, they also don't show the memory. I would like something vaguely like insight, see picture below. Is there any frontend that does that? Or does gdbgui do that and I just didn't figure out how?

[image]

Comment: According to [this](https://www.gdbgui.com/screenshots/#memory-viewer), gdbgui has a memory viewer.

Comment: @ssbssa oh, you are right! But for some reason it doesn't display for me. I guess I have to look into that more...